# Suppressing Section in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a section in my report and Below is my requirement to suppress it:

If scanmode and status=null (these fileds coming from database)
then i need to suppress the section.
If it is not null then i need check next condition  `{Status.status} >= 3` if it is `>=3`  then i need to check next condition `{?Stack} <> "S"`  .

Please suggest the logic i wrote is correct or not>If wrong please modify it

**Logic i wrote:**

```
isnull({Status.scan_mode}) and isnull({Status.status})
```

or

```
{Status.status} >= 3
```

or

```
{?Stack} <> "S"
```

What is my doubt is here we gave or condition for every logic will it check 1st condition,if it is true then  then 2nd ,if it is true then 3rd 
or it will hide the section if any one of above 3 logic's is correct.

Is there any way to convert above logic to if else condition.Can we write if else in suppress condition.If yes please tell me

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Write below logic in supress section

```
If isnull({Status.scan_mode}) 
then
(
if isnull({Status.status}) or {Status.status} >= 3 then 
(
if {?Stack} <> "S"
then
true
)
)
else false
```

Comment: Hi Siva thank you .After checking nulls for both fields isnull({Status.scan_mode}) and isnull({Status.status}).Then I need to check Scanmode in [C,D] also.Then i need to check whether status >= 3 and remaining.Please tell me the code

Answer (score 0):

```
if isnull({Status.scan_mode}) and isnull({Status.status}) then true
else if Scanmode = 'C' or Scanmode = 'D' then true
else if {Status.status} >= 3 or {?Stack} <> "S" then true
else false
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Pratik thank you .After checking nulls for both fields isnull({Status.scan_mode}) and isnull({Status.status}).Then I need to check Scanmode in [C,D] also.Then i need to check whether status >= 3 and remaining.Please tell me the code